# Why am I receiving this warning in a cypress task?

Tags: cypress

I'm running a task to seed my database in a before hook.  Cypress is complaining that

> Cypress Warning: Cypress detected that you returned a promise in a test, but also invoked one or more cy commands inside of that promise.

Here is the task

```
import { seed } from '../../../src/server/db/seed'

const pluginHandler = on => {
  on('task', {
    'seed:db': () => {
      return seed()
    }
  })
}

export default pluginHandler
```

This is the seed function

```
import { exec } from 'child_process'
import util from 'util'

const execP = util.promisify(exec)

export const seed = () => {
  // Drop notes.
  return execP('mongo starter_test --eval "db.notes.drop()"')
    .then(async () => {
      // Insert notes fixtures.
      await execP(
        'mongoimport --db starter_test --collection notes --file ./src/server/db/notes.json'
      )
    })
    .then(() => {
      return 0
    })
}
```

And finally the test, which doesn't do anything yet

```
describe('My First Test', () => {
  before(async () => {
    await cy.task('seed:db')
  })

  it('Does not do much!', () => {
    cy.visit(Cypress.env('HOST'))
  })
})
```

I'm not, as far as I can see, using commands inside the promise as the warning suggests.

Comment: This is a JS logic issue, not DB or anything else. Your 'before' itself isn't async, so it'll just process and wait in the background for that callback, it won't actually resolve with the 'async' like you expect. You likely need a 'done' callback to call after the completion of your callback. Are you using Mocha... if so 'done' is what you're looking for.

Comment: The `before` is async and can normally be async in Mocha, but Cypress doesn't like the `await` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, `async` should not be used inside Cypress `before`, or any other command ([unless you install a 3rd-party lib](https://medium.com/@NicholasBoll/cypress-io-using-async-and-await-4034e9bab207)).

Please try with `before(() => cy.task('seed:db'))`

Comment: Yes, this works (ad you can also use `cy.task(...).then(...)` in other situations, but it gets tripped up with the `await`.